# For which operations a PostGIS Geography index is useful?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, spatial-index, geography-data-type

I need to do KNN- and within-region queries for POI data. I store the POI locations in a geography column. Since I understand that `ST_DISTANCE` doesn't use the geography index, I added a geometry index in order to use the `<->` operator with indexed performance. This works nicely (unfortunately not over the 180° meridian but that's OK in my case).

Now I'm asking myself for which operations a geography index is actually useful?

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial/explanation](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html) seems to contradict your question's premise(?). But the pertinent part says:

> The difference is under the covers: the geography index will correctly handle queries that cover the poles or the international date-line, while the geometry one will not. 
>   There are only a small number of native functions for the geography type:

```
    ST_AsText(geography) returns text
    ST_GeographyFromText(text) returns geography
    ST_AsBinary(geography) returns bytea
    ST_GeogFromWKB(bytea) returns geography
    ST_AsSVG(geography) returns text
    ST_AsGML(geography) returns text
    ST_AsKML(geography) returns text
    ST_AsGeoJson(geography) returns text
    ST_Distance(geography, geography) returns double
    ST_DWithin(geography, geography, float8) returns boolean
    ST_Area(geography) returns double
    ST_Length(geography) returns double
    ST_Covers(geography, geography) returns boolean
    ST_CoveredBy(geography, geography) returns boolean
    ST_Intersects(geography, geography) returns boolean
    ST_Buffer(geography, float8) returns geography [1]
    ST_Intersection(geography, geography) returns geography [1]
```

Comment: I'm aware of the functions for the geography type. My question is which of them actually use the index. `ST_DISTANCE` apparently doesn't.

Comment: The reason why I find this question confusing is that there is no reason to use an index - spatial nor otherwise - to solve a math calculation like finding the distance between two places. So it makes sense that ST_Distance doesn't take advantage of a spatial index. I'd expect the other geography functions that 'use' a spatial index are those that select/operate on a table of geometries, like ST_Intersects, ST_Covers. ie; there's probably no benefit to using an index to writing out a geography to text (ST_AsText).

Comment: I mentioned my use case of k-nearest neighbors (KNN). This basically involves queries like `SELECT * FROM pois, ST_DISTANCE(pois.location, <reference point>) AS Distance ORDER BY Distance DESC LIMIT 10`. It makes a huge difference whether such queries use an index or not.

Comment: I see your point now. Thanks for walking me through it.